# Generate "selected" html tag in a listbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've a Wordpress plugin called "Bookly". It generate a listbox with some values.
I need to get the selected value via Jquery but this selectbox don't generate the selected="selected" when I choose a value.

How can I achieve this ?

**PHP file :**

```
<select id="service" class="bookly-select-mobile bookly-js-select-service">
   <option value=""><?php echo esc_html( Common::getTranslatedOption( 'bookly_l10n_option_service' ) ) ?></option>
</select>
```

**HTML render :**

```
<select id="service" class="bookly-select-mobile bookly-js-select-service">
   <option value="">Choose a service</option>
   <option value="1">Service 1</option>
   <option value="2">Service 2</option>
</select>
```

**What I need :**

```
<select id="service" class="bookly-select-mobile bookly-js-select-service">
   <option value="">Choose a service</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Service 1</option>
   <option value="2">Service 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const service = document.getElementById('service');

service.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

  // wipe previous 'selected' elements
  Array.from(e.target.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach((option) => {
    option.removeAttribute('selected');
  });

  e.target.querySelector(`option[value="${e.target.value}"`).setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
});
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dayun123/fd6Lyasr/) where you can see it in action.